# What does the phrase "Vast majority of people live in the world without" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

As I describe in the question title I want to know the meaning of the phrase highlighted in the following quotation from the [5 August 2012 blog](http://authoredhersh.blogspot.com/2012/08/believing-in-belief.html) of author [Edward Hersh](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1935906577):

> Look around you. Wherever you live, whatever circle of society you are part of, you will notice that the **vast majority of people live in the world without.** Those who are more enlightened, however, are intensely involved with the world within. They realize—as you will, too—that the world within creates the world without.

Comment: I just added the whole paragraph. Can somebody to help me now ? Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @MerianosNikos- at the risk of being persnickety, the word is "phrase" not "phraze", even though the sound is certainly /z/, a voiced silibant.

Comment: What is the reason of downvoting that question ?

Comment: Your original question was «As I describe in the question title I cannot get the meaning of that following phraze: ¶  Vast majority of people live in the world without ¶ Can anybody help me ?». I didn't downvote but imagine that because you quoted only a small fragment and didn't provide a source and showed no research effort you got downvoted.  Had you provided a source, people could have looked up the context.  Better, providing the context in the question makes the question more complete and the answer more obvious.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can see two interpretations of the quote depending on which meaning of "without" is intended.

1. If "without" means lacking and assumes that a word after "without" is missing, then the phrase means something like "Wherever you go someone always has fewer things than you." or "There is always someone worse off than you." or "You don't have it that bad."
2. If "without" means "outside", then the phrase means something more abstruse like "The real world is something that most people never reach." or "Most people never truly enter the world." or "Most people are not present in the moment."

The second interpretation seems less likely, unless this comes from something such as a mystic's journal.

EDIT: @StoneyB is right on. Stylistically, using "without" to mean "outside" and contrast with within is an older usage. It's found in older works and can make a modern work sound older.

Given the added context, I interpret the quote to mean that "most people are focused on the evidence or consequences of a "good" life (a.k.a world without) but not the real means to get there". The sentiment is akin to saying most people watch late-night infomercials about AB-Blasters. Fewer people hit the gym long enough to actually get those toned abs.

Comment: Edited @StoneyB

Answer (score 2):

***Note:*** This is a **General Reference** question, easily answered by any dictionary worthy of the name.

---

The full quote is:

> Look around you. Wherever you live, whatever circle of society you are part of, you will notice that the vast majority of people lives in the world without. Those who are more enlightened, however, are intensely involved with the world within. They realize—as you will, too—that the world within creates the world without.

Here, the words *within* and *without* are being used as modifiers following the nouns they modify and respectively meaning *inside* and *outside*.

So “the world within” simply means “the inside world”, and “the world without” simply means “the outside world”.

A dictionary would have explained this sense of *without*. The OED gives this use as the first of all of them for *without*.  Here is a sampling of relevant senses:

> **I.** Outside, in various senses: opp. to within *adv*. Now only *literary* and somewhat *arch*.
>
> 1. On the outside or outer surface (of a material thing); externally.
> 2. **a.** Outside (or out of) the place mentioned or implied; esp. outside the house or room; out of doors.
>      **b.** *transf*. Outside of a class, body, or community; not in the number or membership; in an alien or foreign community. those (that are) without = ‘outsiders’. Now only in echoes of 1 Cor. v. 12.
> 3. *fig*. and *gen*. Outside of the inward being, soul, or mind; with regard to external actions or circumstances; in relation to others or to something other than the self; sometimes, in outward appearance as opposed to inward reality; outwardly.
> 4. Used *absol*. by ellipsis of *obj*., in opposition to **within** (or *in*) *prep*., where it has the appearance of an *adv*.